# Microsoft Project: How to make two resources work at the same time on the same task when using automatic resource leveling?

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

In Microsoft Project I have a task with these attributes:

- Duration = 0.5 days
- Resources = Person A[100%]; Person B[100%]
- Type = Fixed Duration
- Effort driven = No (implying Level Assignments = No)

When I start Resource Leveling (with "Leveling can adjust individual assignments on a task" = No), the duration of the task will be increased because Microsoft Project schedules the assignment the following way: Person A starts to work at 08:00 and finishes at 12:00. Person B starts to work at 13:00 and finishes at 17:00.

I actually need to have the two persons working together at the same time.

How can I tell Microsoft Project to schedule the assignments of the two persons to have the same time start and finish times? (When doing automatic resource leveling.)

*(Or put generally: How to automatically level resources without increases in duration of my fixed-duration multi-resource tasks?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was caused by using different calendars.

In a post by Project MVP Jan De Messemaeker that I found in [thread in a Microsoft Office forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_project-mso_winother/two-resource-to-work-on-one-task-at-the-same-time/4a4d3b8e-705c-4e75-b855-a0352100ef8c), it was suggested to give all resources the same calendar and create manually scheduled "dummy tasks" that represent off-times (like individual vacations).

When doing so, automatic leveling worked like a charm in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Although resource calendars can play a role, the fundamental issue in the case described is the "Leveling can adjust individual assignments on a task" leveling option.  Checking the box allows resources to work independently, letting the task start as soon as logical predecessors are satisfied and the first resource is available, but extending the task's duration until the last resource finishes its work.  Leaving the box unchecked (i.e. the default option) keeps all the work within the original duration of the task during leveling, so the resources work together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did uncheck "Leveling can adjust individual assignments on a task" - but that did not solve my issue in the first place. I'll add this information to the initial question.

Comment: Well, now you are describing behavior that I'm not familiar with, so there's no more I can say.  Good luck.t

Answer (score 0):

Load the two resources as a team, i.e., you have person A, person B, and Team A which contains both persons.  Combine their rates.